# C# detecting if email not registered

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I need some help with a code

```
protected void btSubscribe_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    try {
        string activationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        bool exists = false;
        string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Database/db.xlsx");
        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
    "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", fileName);
        using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
            try {
                cn.Open();
                using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM [subscritionEmails$] WHERE [COLUMN1] = @email", cn)) {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", subscriberEmail.Text.Trim());
                    exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(exists);
                if(exists) {
                    errorMessage.InnerHtml = "O email que foi indicado já existe na nossa base de dados.";
                } else {
                    try {
                        using(OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [subscritionEmails$] " + "([COLUMN1],[COLUMN2],[COLUMN3]) " + "VALUES('@value1', '@value2','0')", cn)) {
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", subscriberEmail.Text);
                            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", activationKey);
                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        //EnviarEmails(subscriberEmail.Text, activationKey);
                        errorMessage.InnerHtml = "O seu pedido foi registado com sucesso. Obrigado.";
                        subscriberEmail.Text = "";
                        subscriberName.Text = "";
                    } catch(Exception data) {
                        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowErrors"].ToString() == "1") {
                            errorMessage.InnerHtml = data.ToString();
                        } else {
                            errorMessage.InnerHtml = "Lamentamos mas não foi possível registar o seu pedido. P.f. tente novamente.";
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception conError) {
                if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowErrors"].ToString() == "1") {
                    errorMessage.InnerHtml = conError.ToString();
                } else {
                    errorMessage.InnerHtml = "Lamentamos mas não foi possível registar o seu pedido. P.f. tente novamente.";
                }
            } finally {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception eMail) {
        if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowErrors"].ToString() == "1") {
            errorMessage.InnerHtml = eMail.ToString();
        } else {
            errorMessage.InnerHtml = "Lamentamos mas não foi possível registar o seu pedido. P.f. tente novamente.";
        }
    } finally {
        errorMessage.Visible = true;
        //Page.ClimentScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JS1", "window.top.location = ('WebForm1.aspx');", true);
        UpdateNews.Update();
    }
}
```

---

Ok Thank's to @Steve I've fixed 2nd part of the code, but now after i add the email and try again to add it, it shows me the message that the email was already added, but when i open the xlsx the file is still the same, nothing was added...

Comment: You're asking what you're doing wrong, but haven't said what is happening that you're not expecting. Tell us how it doesn't work.

Comment: We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't even tell us what the problem is to begin with.

Comment: it gives me the error above, and stops the code

Comment: You parameter name is `@email` not `email`.

Comment: To use column names you should be sure that your excel sheets has the column names in the first row and your connection string has HDR=YES. Moreover, you search a sheet named subscribers and then add the new line to another sheet.

Comment: @MattBurland OleDb parameters are nameless. You could name them as you wish but you should respect the placeholders order

Comment: Could you add the connectionstring used to the code above?

Comment: I've updated the code, there is all there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your connection string you have HDR=YES. This means that the first row of your sheet should contain the column names. So you have two options.

1. Insert the column name COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 in the first row of your
   sheets
2. Remove HDR=YES, but change your query to

   ```
   "SELECT count(*) FROM [subscribers$] WHERE [F1] = @email"
   ```

and the second query to

```
    "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] " + "([F1],[F2]) VALUES(@value1, @value2)"
```

Comment: Ok I've used your 1st sugestion and it kinda worked, but i've added he email manually to the excel file and it still returns that it doesn't find the email, what can it be?

Comment: Not sure about it, my tests show that this should work unless you have some hidden spaces or the letter case is different.

Comment: Just see your last edit. Why you add the % to the parameter name? and remove those single quotes around the parameter placeholder. With those quotes the parameter placeholder becomes a literal string and, of course the search for a literal %email% will fail

Comment: yeh i've fixed that sorry, but it still doesn't work, gonna fix here too

Comment: Cannot find any error now, did you save the excel file right?

Comment: yes, but can you send me your excel file please since it's working fine, it may be mine that since it's not the English office it may conflict with the code..

Comment: Don't think that this will make any difference, but here the file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26176237/test.xlsx

Comment: Instead what happens if you change your query to select everything in that sheet and load a datatable. Then use the debugger to check if the table contains your record.

Comment: Something weird is happening, everything seems to work fine, it gives me the message that the email was added, and when i try again it shows me that the email was already added, but when i open the xlsx everything is the same, no data was added.

Comment: Do you have the file XLSX listed in your projects files?

Comment: yes, i do, i open it in the visual studio explorer, and with normal explorer, and even get it from the site, and it's still like the one you send, that i didn't change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58395/discussion-between-steve-and-nikato).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure [Column1] is the correct column name?. I get this error when the column name does not match the name used in the query.

Comment: i don't, in my excel 1st column apears as "A", nothing else

Answer (score -2):

Try splitting line 33 into two lines. In the first, save `(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()` as an int. In the second, compare the int to 0 for your `bool exists`.

Comment: That won't help at all.